# Magento 2 : Can't enable product

Tags: magento2

I setup a Magento 2.0.4 website, added some products and then gave access to the store owner to add remaining products.
Some of them were added using duplicate function and were disabled by default.

In **PRODUCTS => CATALOG** I selected them, clicked on **ACTIONS => CHANGE STATUS => ENABLE**.

Some of them are still disabled.

Products seem fine:

- PRODUCT ONLINE
- Quantity: 100 - In Stock

Inventory:

- Manage Stock: no
- Min quantity in shopping cart: 1
- Max: 10000

Maybe I'm missing something since I'm unable to set them as Enabled.

Magento version: 2.0.4

Store is in Developer mode.

EDIT: I just updated to Magento 2.0.5 and I don't see any change

Comment: I am also having same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This issue occur when you have multi store website. 
If you are not able to enable the products from admin please follow the below steps:-

- Edit the product and change the store view and enable the product from that store.
- Enable the product from all store and save the products

you can now able to  enable the product.
reindex using command, and check the product on frontend.

Hope this solution solve your issue.

Comment: wow, thanks, all i need to do is reindex using this cmd:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex :)